# How to print the correct value from future instance in flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch a field name "total" from mongodb and add all the total for a particular user as shown below

```
  getCartTotal() async{

    var total = 0;
    Db db = new Db("mongodb://3.133.123.227/Kartofilldatabasetest");
    await db.open();
    var collection =  db.collection('cart');
    await collection.find({"customerId":phoneNumber}).forEach((v) {
      total = total + v["total"];

    });
    db.close();
    
    return total;

  }
```

I am trying to use the returned value of total as follow
in the init function i am calling it everytime the page is opened.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      await getTotal();
    });
  }

  getTotal() async {

     totalCartValue = await Mongocart(phoneNumber: widget.phoneNumber,description: '',image: '',price: '',quantity: '',total: '').getCartTotal();




  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print(totalCartValue);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Whenever i am trying to print the value it shows instance of future and not the value is printed.
This is what is getting printed Instance of 'Future'

Below is my database screenshot

[image]

I want fetch the field total of all the object and assign it in the totalcartvalue currently it is printing 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Make the variable explicitly the type you want it to be and then follow the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Comment: I have edited my question .. Could you please check

Comment: To be honest, that seems to be an incredibly "hacky" thing to do. Please read the link I posted, it contains a tutorial how to properly work with futures.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `async` in the `getTotal()` function, the result should be using `await`, otherwise it would just build concurrently with the data is being retrieve, thus no data is displayed on build.

```
@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        await getTotal();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question .. Could you please check